# HTML downloaded with curl turns up empty in my browser

Tags: html, curl

I'm trying to run the command

`curl https://www.spoonrocket.com > indexspoon.html`

and I get back a page full of html and stuff. However when I place the html file in my browser it is empty. I'm trying to figure it out but came up with nothing. Why does the file look empty when I have it in my browser, but in actuality there is actually a lot of content in indexspoon.html?

Answer (score 0):

This is not an issue with curl, it appears to be an issue with your browser...modern browsers have tightened up their security on making cross domain request. This can help to prevent fatal attacks such as "Man in the Middle".

I notice that your HTML document has scripts that use jquery which makes Ajax request..

Most browsers have a built it web console and a debugger.
On the Menubar of your broswer

Tools--->web developer--->web console

you will notice in you console, their is a fatal error

```
NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI: Access to restricted URI denied
```

It appears that one of the scripts in the html document is making ajax request using jquery which is being blocked by your browser

click the `Debugger` tab next to your web console window and you will notice this